# error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java, printwriter

I'm trying to create a simple program that will output a string to a text file. Using code I found here, I have put together the following code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Testing {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File ("file.txt");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
    printWriter.println ("hello");
    printWriter.close();       
  }
}
```

J-grasp throws me the following error:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g Testing.java

Testing.java:10: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
                              ^
1 error

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
```

Since I'm pretty new to Java, I have no idea what this means. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Search the internet for `java exception tutorial` and work through one of the tutorials you find.

Comment: For starters, and simple one-off programs, add the `throws FileNotFoundException` (or, to be more general, `throws IOException`) to the `main` header line, as Black Panther suggests.  As you get more sophisticated you'll want to use try/catch handlers, but one step at a time.

Comment: +1 for a well-stated question, though you probably could have found an answer if you had searched a little harder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are not telling the compiler that there is a chance to throw a `FileNotFoundException` 
a `FileNotFoundException` will be thrown if the file does not exist.

try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File ("file.txt");
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    try
    {
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file);
        printWriter.println ("hello");
        printWriter.close();       
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)  
    {
        // insert code to run when exception occurs
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Managed to get it up and running :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're very new to Java, and just trying to learn how to use `PrintWriter`, here is some bare-bones code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class SimpleFile {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        PrintWriter writeMe = new PrintWriter("newFIle.txt");
        writeMe.println("Just writing some text to print to your file ");
        writeMe.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a `PrintWriter` might throw an exception if there is something wrong with the file, like if the file doesn't exist. so you have to add

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
```

then it will compile and use a `try..catch` clause to catch and process the exception.

Answer (score -1):

This means that when you call `new PrintWriter(file)`, it can throw an exception when the file you want to write to doesn't exist. So you either need to handle that exception, or make your code re-throw it for the caller to handle.

```java
import java.io.*;

public class Testing {

    /**
     * This writes a string to a file.
     * If an exception occurs, we don't care if nothing gets written.
     */
    public void writeToFileWithoutThrowingExceptions(File file, String text) {
        // Yes, we could use try-with-resources here,
        // but that would muddy the example.
        PrintWriter printWriter;
        try {
            printwriter = new PrintWriter(file);
            printWriter.println(text);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            // Do something with that exception to handle it.
            // Since we said we don't care if our text does not get written,
            // we just print the exception and move on.
            // Printing the exception like this is usually a bad idea, since
            // now no-one knows about it. Logging is better, but even better
            // is figuring out what we need to do when that exception occurs.
            System.out.println(fnfe);
        } finally {
            // Whether an exception was thrown or not,
            // we do need to close the printwriter.
            printWriter.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This writes a string to a file.
     * If an exception occurs, we re-throw it and let the caller handle it.
     */
    public void writeToFileThrowingExceptions(File file, String text) throws FileNotFoundException {
        // We use try-with-resources here. This takes care of closing
        // the PrintWriter, even if an exception occurs.
        try (PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(file)) {
            printWriter.println(text);
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("file.txt");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        // We call the method that doesn't throw an exception
        writeToFileWithoutThrowingExceptions(file, "Hello");
        
        // Then we call the method that _can_ throw an exception
        try {
            writeToFileThrowingExceptions(file, "World");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            // Since this method can throw an exception, we need to handle it.
            // Note that now we have different options for handling it, since             
            // we are now letting the caller handle it.
            // The caller could decide to try and create another file, send
            // an e-mail, or just log it and move on.
            // Again, as an example, we just print the exception, but as we
            // discussed, that is not the best way of handling one.
            System.out.println(fnfe);
        }
    }
}
```